# pip install - killed

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I'm trying to install package with pip on Ubuntu server:

```
$ pip install MySQLdb
Downloading/unpacking MySQLdb
Killed
```

And it's getting killed. There is enough free RAM on server. Why it is killed?

UPD
Logs:

> Out of memory: Kill process 6627 (pip) score 297 or sacrifice child

Thats strange, because I have about 150 mb free RAM.

Comment: Anything in `/var/log/kern.log`? Or run `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` and try installing again.

Comment: On another note the package name is actually `mysql-python` but that does not explain your output

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to check logs, depending on the version of ubuntu and stuff, it should be in `/var/log/messages` or at least in `/var/log` so you can grep python or pip in that folder. This should provide hints.

Also, if you're not in a virtualenv, you should probably use `sudo` to perform (implicit) privileged operations, such as copying the library in the global lib folder.

Comment: I was in virtualenv, still had to use sudo to get the installation successfully done. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Using sudo in a virtualenv sounds like there is something seriously wrong with your setup. Are you sure `pip` came from your virtualenv?

Answer (score 306):

If you are running low on memory you could try with `pip install <your-package-name> --no-cache-dir`

Comment: I'm shocked that helps with low RAM, but it helps

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! I ran out of memory in previous installation attempt, then made some more space and the subsequent installation attempt was just printing "Killed". I guess it was reading the corrupt files from cache?

Comment: Solution confirmed (also for tensorflow, and mysql), @artem should check it as correct answer

Comment: For those who are using `pipenv`; I've had the same experience with scarce memory. So what I did was kill all gunicorn processes from systemd which freed enough memory to allow me to run `pipenv install` again.

Comment: I am actually surprised that cache was the problem but this worked for me!

Comment: Works for opencv-python as well.

Comment: this solved me for tensorflow on vps server

Comment: It helped on my raspberry pi zero w which has little RAM

Comment: Helped on my digitalocean droplet installing pytorch (which itself may not be a great idea).

Answer (score 12):

If the `--no-cache-dir` flag isn't enough, try increasing the swap space.

I was trying to install PyTorch on a Linode server which had 2GB RAM and 512 of Swap space. Adding 2GB of Swap space solved the issue.

> Method # 3 : Create a swap file.
>
> 1. Create a swap file on the current File system for example on root, for this a new Directory can be created.
>    $ sudo mkdir /swap
> 2. Create a new file into this new directory, in this example a new file for 2Gb is create.
>    $ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap/swapfile1 bs=1M count=2048
> 3. Create a new swap area on the file that has been created.
>    $ sudo mkswap  /swap/swapfile1
> 4. Change the permissions on the file.
>    $ sudo chmod 600 /swap/swapfile1
> 5. Add the swap partition to the /etc/fstab file as indicated below on this step:
>    /swap/swapfile1    swap   swap      defaults       0 0
> 6. Load the new swap space that had been created for the Instance.
>    $ sudo swapon -a

Source for Guide: [TheGeekDiary](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/3-ways-of-increasing-swap-space-on-linux/)

Comment: If you just temporarily need the swap space you can skip step 5 and replace step 6 with `sudo swapon /swap/swapfile1` and then when done run `swapoff /swap/swapfile1` to disable the swap and then you can clean up the file and get the space back with `rm /swap/swapfile1` or `rm -rf /swap` if you're done with the whole folder.

Answer (score 9):

In my case the cleaning cache of pip by using `pip3 cache purge` was was the solution, but be careful: it removes the entire pip cache.

I have enough free RAM in idle state (~3Gb) but installation of torch being killed again and again, even without showing downoading progress:

```
Collecting torch>=1.5.0
Killed
```

So I supposed, just like @embiem guessed, that I had corrupted files in the cache, because I had aborted installation of the dependencies for the module once. After clearing the whole pip cache the installation was successful (And 15GB of free disk space was freed up - I use a lot of virtual environments). You can check brief info with `pip3 cache info` and all cache managing command `pip3 cache -h`, it's very useful in some cases.

Answer (score 6):

#### Step1:

`pip install package --no-cache-dir`
If the problem persists, go to step 2.

#### Step2:

`sudo swapoff -a`

`sudo swapon -a`

Then try step 1 again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this error and the process was getting killed for the torch package.
Then I browsed the web and found the solution.

```
cd ~/.cache
mv pip pip.bk
```

This cleared the cache memory with regards to pip. Uninstalling and installing pip did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue when installing `torch` as one of the dependencies. I checked that during the installation process it overshoots the RAM utilization as reported by logs. In my case, during the peak it increases the RAM usage to almost +3GB.

I just closed the Firefox instance that was using almost 1GB from my 6GB laptop and run `pip install` again an it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was using *SLURM* and tried to install packages on the login node. Should also fix the problems when using other workload managers e.g. IBM spectrum LSF. 
I first needed to use my allocated resources with `srun --pty bash` (case for slurm) and then it worked fine.