# pip killed when installing requirements

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, pip

I'm deploying a container onto an AWS server. I can build the container no problem on my laptop, but when building on the instance it gets killed when running pip install -r requirements.txt.

Some more info:

I have checked in var/log as suggested here: [pip install - killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30550235/pip-install-killed) But there are no log outputs.

The instance has 2 cores and 4G ram

My laptop has 4 cores and 4G ram

Running Top, CPU usage spikes from the outset, and just before it dies ram starts to spike.

I've seen some people suggesting using no-cache on pip. But there's conflicting information about whether that saves ram or harddrive space.

Any idea what causes this, and how I can deal with it? I've never had pip crash on me before.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /requirements
Add . /requirements
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt 

WORKDIR /application
EXPOSE 80
ENV CODING_LOCATION production
CMD python aex_training_controller.py -prs
```

requirements.txt (After stripping half of it away)

```
nltk==3.4
numpy==1.16.0
pandas==0.23.4
Pebble==4.3.9
git+https://github.com/boudinfl/pke.git
requests==2.21.0
seaborn==0.9.0
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
spacy==2.0.18
symspellpy==6.3.5
textblob==0.15.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting an error `Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'` file not found here.

I have updated Dockerfile as follow and it is working.

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY requirements requirements
WORKDIR /requirements
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt 

WORKDIR /application
EXPOSE 80
ENV CODING_LOCATION production
CMD python aex_training_controller.py -prs
```