# Torch library is getting killed when I try to install it on my shared hosting server

Tags: python, pytorch, cpanel, torch

I have a python based package, whose dependency is torch==1.7.0.

When I run command `pip install torch` it is giving the error:

```
Collecting torch==1.7.0
  Downloading torch-1.7.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (776.7 MB)
     |############################### | 776.7 MB 18.8 MB/s eta 0:00:01Killed
```

This library is successfully installed when the installation command is run on my laptop. But i have to install it on my shared hosting server. When i try installing it on the server, the install kills and gave the error mentioned above.

Comment: Might be worth a shot: [pip install - killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30550235/pip-install-killed)

Comment: Thank you! command mentioned in the link "pip install torch --no-cache-dir" worked!